# setTimeout в GET запросе

Tags: jquery, get

По непонятным мне причинам, в консоль записывается **1**, хотя, как мне кажется, должен записываться **id** **с запроса** (`var id = result[i].id`). Всё, что до setTimeout, делается правильно, а вот в самом setTimeout неправильно (`console.log(id)` записывает 1 вместо правильного id).

```
var lots = {
 realtime: function() {
  $.getJSON('/lots/realtime', {

  }, function(data) {
   var result = data;

   for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var id = result[i].id;
    var result_amount = result[i].result_amount;
    var last_bet_user_login = result[i].last_bet_user_login;

    var old_result_amount = parseFloat($('#lot_id'+id).find('.all_summ_amount').text());

    if(old_result_amount != result_amount) {
     $('#lot_id'+id).find('.all_summ_amount').html(result_amount);

     $('#lot_id'+id).find('.bet_last_login').html('Возможный победитель: <br /> <span>'+last_bet_user_login+'</span>');

     $('#lot_id'+id).find('.all_summ').addClass('active');
     $('#lot_id'+id).find('.time').addClass('active');

     setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(id);

      $('#lot_id'+id).find('.all_summ').removeClass('active');
      $('#lot_id'+id).find('.time').removeClass('active');
     }, 200);
    }
   }

   setTimeout(function() {
    lots.realtime();
   }, 1000);
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Блоки `for` и `if` не создают *замыканий*. Дело в том, что функция, передающаяся в `setTimout` содержит не значение `result[i].id`, а ссылку на это значение.
Как итог, все ваши функции вызываемые через таймаут получают в своем замыкании не конкретное значение каждой итерации цикла `result[0].id, result[1].id ... result[result.length-1].id`, а только последнее значение, присвоенное последней итерацией, а именно `result[result.length-1].id`, которое по всей видимости и содержит значение 1.

Чтобы это исправить, создайте новую функцию

```
function timeoutHandler(id){
    return function(){
        console.log(id);
        $('#lot_id'+id).find('.all_summ').removeClass('active');
        $('#lot_id'+id).find('.time').removeClass('active');
    }
}
```

и передавайте ее в `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(timeoutHandler(id), 200);
```

Comment: отлично, работает! Спасибо огромное за подробное разъяснение :)

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout()` асинхронна. По сути, она не поспевает за вашим циклом, когда вы вновь ей передаете переменную на каждой интерации.

Необходимо весь цикл обернуть в `setTimeout()`:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    alert(i);
  }
}, 200);
```

### Update #1

Тогда Вам необходимо собрать все Ваши id, к примеру, в массив и уже потом отправить этот массив в `setTimeout()`:

```js
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  result.push(i);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  result.forEach(function(value) {
    alert(value);
  });
}, 200);
```

### Update #2

т.е. конкретно в вашем примере, передать переменную `result`

```
for(var i = 0, len = result.length; i < len; i++) {
    var id = result[i].id;

    //ваш код
}

// а только затем setTimeout()
setTimeout(
    function() {
        result.forEach(function (value) {
            var el = $('#lot_id' + value.id);
            el.find('.all_summ').removeClass('active');
            el.find('.time').removeClass('active');
        })
    },
    200
);
```

Comment: а смысл весь цикл в setTimeout? Мне же нужно через 200мс удалить class у определенного элемента.

Comment: @ModaL Дополнил ответ.